# Equation for a line passing a point by angle of T and extending a certain length

Tags: line, point

How can I get the start and end points of a `Line` that its center is at `Point(x,y)` and has an angle of `T` to x-axis? The length of the Line is 2*L.

[image]

Comment: Interesting question, but you are aware that this is a programming StackExchange, not Mathematics?  I think you might find the answer to this question in any good coordinate geometry text.  I suggest MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mathematics, not programming.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist I'm aware actually but I saw some other questions that would be considered as math questions but were here So I risked asking the question. Anyway if we consider these as computational geometry questions we are not that wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some unfathomable reason I found myself fascinated by this question.  But I will provide my answer in terms of C# code.  Building off Donald Berk's answer (which I found to have an error as originally posted, see my comment to his answer), I created the following console application.

To prove the equation, I drew a known line with coordinates (2,1) (6,5).  The angle of the line is 45 deg, or 0.7853 rad.  The line's total length is 5.6569, with a midpoint coordinate of (4,3).  When I plugged in the values of the midpoint coordinate, line length, and angle, I got the correct start and end points.  This was how I discovered that Donald's original answer was incorrect -- probably a copy/paste error.

```
using System;

namespace LineMuncher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Line myLine = CoordinateGeometry.GetLineFromMidpointCoord(0.7853d, 4.0d, 3.0d, 5.6569d);

            Console.WriteLine("Start({0},{1}) : End({2},{3})"
                , Math.Round(myLine.StartPoint.X)
                , Math.Round(myLine.StartPoint.Y)
                , Math.Round(myLine.EndPoint.X)
                , Math.Round(myLine.EndPoint.Y));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class CoordinateGeometry
    {
        public static Line GetLineFromMidpointCoord(
            double Angle, double MidPointX, double MidPointY, double Len)
        {
            Line theLine = new Line();

            theLine.StartPoint.X = MidPointX - ((Len / 2.0d) * Math.Sin(Angle));
            theLine.StartPoint.Y = MidPointY - ((Len / 2.0d) * Math.Cos(Angle));

            theLine.EndPoint.X = MidPointX + ((Len / 2.0d) * Math.Sin(Angle));
            theLine.EndPoint.Y = MidPointY + ((Len / 2.0d) * Math.Cos(Angle));

            return theLine;
        }
    }

    public class Line
    {
        public Line()
        {
            StartPoint = new Coordinate();
            EndPoint = new Coordinate();
        }

        public Coordinate StartPoint { get; set; }
        public Coordinate EndPoint { get; set; }

    }

    public class Coordinate
    {
        public Coordinate()
        {
            X = 0.0d;
            Y = 0.0d;
        }
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I figured out the typo the other day when implementing it in my program, then forgot to edit the answer. The answer you provided is correct. By the way, I like your style of programming.

Answer (score 2):

Start point is

```
(x - L·sin(T), y - L·cos(T))
```

End point is

```
(x + L·sin(T), y + L·cos(T))
```

Comment: Thanks Donald, it's been a while since I studied geometry at college.

Comment: +1 for your answer, but I checked your answer and it has an error.  The Endpoint Y coordinate formula should be: y + L·cos(T).  See my answer for how I found the error.  You might want to amend your answer.

Comment: Thank you, Cyberherbalist, for the catch. It was my first ever reply and I just blew it.